# Android Application closes suddenly after launching when trying to run with appium & ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium

I am trying to automate an android application using Ruby-Appium (Ruby Cucumber framework)
When I am trying to run my automated tests, the app gets launched & closes suddenly without performing any operation.

Appium capabilities:

```
[caps]
platformName = "android"
deviceName = "HTC"
udid = "DEVICEID"
app = "../package/myApp.apk"
noReset = true
fullReset = false

[appium_lib]
port = "4500"
```

Appium Driver Created: (reading the above capabilities from a file and passing it as a parameter while creating driver)

```
Appium::Driver.new(caps)
```

Not sure, why the application closes without performing any operation.

Can anyone please assist me on how to get to the root cause?

Comment: not much learned on ruby cucumber framework but I hope you have some tests after creating driver session and you are not calling a driver kill directly post creation. Any exception thrown while creating a driver?

Comment: yes, I do have tests after creating driver object. No exception is thrown while creating the driver. 
No error logs were observed on adb logcat.

Comment: `adb logcat` would not print the details for you. You can look into the appium server logs for that

Comment: appium server works fine. Application closes after launch & my tests failed giving an error STATUS 500. 
After looking into the appium server logs, it says STATUS 500, element was not found.

Comment: It would be great to see the appium logs shared.

Comment: That was the problem with the application itself. I tried the same setup with the other app and it worked fine. Thanks.